# 2 possible joincolumns (entity can be in either)

Tags: hibernate

The problem I'm having is that I have a database setup like this:

```
table bla
--------
id id



Table foo
--------
id id

bla fk1 to bla

bla2 fk2 to bla
```

Now I want to map this to an entity/DTO, and whilst it's perfectly doable using 2 list variables annotated with `oneToMany` in `bla`, I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a cleaner solutions than just merging these 2 variables in my dto mapper (my current solution) as I couldn't find anything useful in the hibernate documentation.

Comment: I would not know how, and I would not know, why... If the DB design isn't completely strange, these two references will have two different purposes.

Comment: @UweAllner reasoning is so that a user can select that either bla_a or bla_b can be selected but not both. But it doesn't matter if bla_a is bla or bla2. That's why I want it to end up in 1 list for convenience sake.